# el tamaño de una aplicación web influye de alguna forma en su rendimiento o calidad?

Tags: laravel, spring, aplicación-web

tengo una pregunta cuando usamos un framework para desarrollar una aplicación web pesa mas que cuando no usamos framework, esto es por que el framework viene con librerías que al final no se utiliza en proyectos simples, mi pregunta  es si el tamaño o lo que pesa un proyecto influye en el rendimiento de la aplicacion?

Answer (score 0):

Buen día, la carpeta `vendor` que utiliza el `composer` para bajar las dependencias que utiliza un `Framework` aunque no se utilicen todas pero por alguna razón se incluyen, esto es porque muchas librerías son necesarias para hacer determinadas funciones, no creo que eso pueda afectar en algo el rendimiento de alguna web.

En todo caso, si llegaras a borrar alguna de estás, posiblemente puedas experimentar errores al momento de ejecutar tu app web.

Answer (score 0):

Los frameworks como Laravel, cuentan con muchas herramientas para optimizar el rendimiento de una aplicación, y para facilitar la interacción con diferentes servicios, como la base de datos, email, pdf, etc.

Más allá del tamaño que puedan ocupar los archivos del framework, su uso esta preparado para mejorar el rendimiento de cualquier aplicación, y para optimizarla. Por ejemplo, Laravel cuenta con las librerías correspondientes para minificar css, es decir, comprimir los diferentes archivos css que se puedan tener, en uno solo. Por supuesto, es necesario entender como funciona este tipo de características dentro del framework, para utilizarlas, y esto a veces no es simple.

El uso de un framework, va a depender un poco del tamaño del desarrollo a realizar.

En general, diría que si se tiene que desarrollar una aplicación, con login y/o registración de usuarios, es conveniente utilizar algún tipo de framework.

Saludos